# Find number of distinct circles formed by taking 3 of n given points

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, geometry

Given n number of points in an array with x and y co ordinates, we have to tell number of distinct circles that can be formed from taking three points at a time points.

The only logic I could think of was to take three points and find their circum centre and count the circles having common circum centre but could not write efficient code for it, can someone please help with a better logic or how to implement the same logic?

Comment: Finding the circumcenter of three points (the center of the circle) is not enough--you also need the radius of the circle. Otherwise you may think points are on the same circle when they are on concentric circles. The [second method here](https://qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/circle%20given%203%20points.htm) seems to be efficient. Have you tried coding that? One more thing--do you consider a line through three co-linear points to be a "circle" in this problem?

Comment: @RoryDaulton every triangle inscribers a circle so it is possible to calculate it

Comment: @RoryDaulton I would actually think that method 3 is more efficient.  And if the perpendicular bisectors are parallel, then it is a straight line.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Rory not only said it was possible, he linked to a list of ways to carry out the calculation.  But that returns us to the point that when we ask how many circles are  made out of the points `(0, 0)`, `(1, 1)`, `(2, 2)`, and `(3, 3)` there are contexts in which the natural answer is 1, and others in which it is 0.  The OP needs to know which answer they are looking for.

Comment: If all you want is the number of unique circles, then you just need to know the number of unique triples in your array. And, if a straight line doesn't define a circle, then you have to filter out the triples that have three colinear points.

Comment: @JimMischel Different triples may describe the same circle.

Comment: @user58697 Hmmmm ... You're right. So you will have to compute the equation.

Comment: @RoryDaulton provides a nice list of ways to calculate the circles.  If the input points have integer coordinates, then method 1 in that list is advantageous, since it's easy to get *exact* rational answers from it.  Since each instance of the same circle would produce exactly the same 6 integers in the result (3 numerators and 3 denominators), you could use a simple hash set to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on "Circumscribed circle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2) gives what is probably the most efficient way to find the center of the circle from the coordinates of the three points. There are some obvious minor efficiencies you could add, such as pre-calculating `Ax^2 + Ay^2` in advance.